# LINE login api authentication doesn't work after I've accepted the agreement

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm developing a web app using node.js and use ejs as my view engine.
On my login page, I am trying to intergrate LINE login in my system.

I followed the instructions and tried run on the the login querystring in the following order,

```
access.line.me/dialog/oauth/weblogin?response_type=code&client_id={My Channel ID}&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/login&state=login
```

but the page shows "Can not connect to this site page." Tried refresh many times and it is still not working.

I've tried looking for the issue, but I still don't get why my login page is not showing up. Did I do anything wrong?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

I think u cant use localhost url as your login url, it must be hosted and have https security

Comment: Thank you I've got it fixed.